# When can the Angular onpush notification strategy be used?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

Suppose we have a counter component like the one below that knows how to mutate its state and could have a button that triggers the `increment()` function, etc.

```
    @Component({...})
    export class CounterComponent {

    @Input()
    count: number = 0;

    increment() {
        this.count++;
    }

    decrement() {
        this.count--;
    }

  }
```

Does that disqualify it from an `OnPush` notification strategy?  In other words must components that qualify for `OnPush` not mutate their own state.

Comment: This looks like a fairly common scenario and candidate for Angulars default change detection strategy. Also the @Input decorator is not used in the parent component, but rather the child component. In the code you provided is CounterComponent a child component?

Comment: Yes the CounterComponent would be the child.  Attempting to fence in the requirements for properly implementing the `OnPush` strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since counter is number but not object its value will be just copied to child component. So changing it inside will not affect changeDetection mechanism. Bacuse onpush trategy start change detection only on input value changes from parent perspective. So if you want view reflection when you change counter inside the component - use default change strategy.

Comment: So if IIUC don't use onPush with this component, because the component's template will only be updated when the parent pushes a value and not when the counter increment/decrement functions trigger a change in the components state?